# Error NoClassDefFoundError Al Convertir .xls a .xlsx

Tags: java, excel, netbeans

Tengo un Error al querer Convertir dicho archivo con un metodo de la siguiente clase:

```
public class ProcesaArchivo {
UtilArchivo util = new UtilArchivo();
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
String fileCodigo = s + "/codificacion_";
String fileCodigoLV = s + "/codificacion_LV.csv";
Map<String, String> codigosMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

public ProcesaArchivo() {
    //
}

public String procesaLibro(String nomArchivo, String dirSalida,int año, String mes, String tipoLibro)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    List cellDataList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream((nomArchivo));
        XSSFWorkbook wBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);// <------ Linea en Conflicto
        XSSFSheet hssfSheet = wBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIterator = hssfSheet.rowIterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow hssfRow = (XSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
            Iterator iterator = hssfRow.cellIterator();
            List cellTempList = new ArrayList();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) iterator.next();
                cellTempList.add(hssfCell);
            }
            cellDataList.add(cellTempList);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return "ERROR: Formato de archivo no valido: " + ex.getMessage();
    }
    if(tipoLibro.equals("LC")) {
        return escribeLibroCompra(cellDataList,dirSalida,año,mes,tipoLibro);
    } else {
        return escribeLibroVenta(cellDataList,dirSalida,año,mes,tipoLibro);
    }
}

private String escribeLibroVenta(List cellDataList, String dirSalida, int año, String mes, String tipoLibro) throws IOException {
    String outputFile = dirSalida + "/" + tipoLibro  + "_" + mes +  año  + "_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".csv";
    String encCompra =  "TipoLibro;TipoDoc;NroDoc;FechaDoc;Anulado;RutDoc;RazonSoc;MontoNeto;MontoExe;MontoIVA;TasaImp;MntTotal";

    try {
        ArrayList filas = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList celdas = new ArrayList();

        //pregunta si existe el archivo scv de compra o venta
        boolean alreadyExists = new File(outputFile).exists();
        if(alreadyExists) {
            File archivoLibro = new File(outputFile);
            archivoLibro.delete();
        }

        CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true), '\t');
        csvOutput.write(encCompra);
        csvOutput.endRecord();
        for (int i = 3; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) {
            List cellTempList = (List) cellDataList.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < cellTempList.size(); j++) {
                XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) cellTempList.get(j);
                celdas.add(hssfCell.toString());
            }
            filas.add(celdas);
            celdas = new ArrayList();
        }

        int salida = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < filas.size() ; x++) {
            ArrayList fila = (ArrayList) filas.get(x);
            if(fila.size() < 9 ){
                continue;
            }
            if(fila.get(0).toString().toLowerCase().contains("cuadro")){
                salida = 1;
                break;
            }
            if(!fila.get(0).toString().toLowerCase().contains("total")) {
                Date fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", new Locale("es", "CL")).parse(fila.get(0).toString());
                String fechaDoc = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(fecha);
                String razonSoc = cortaTexto(fila.get(1).toString(),45);
                String rutDoc = fila.get(2).toString();
                String nDoc = getQuitaMontoCeros(fila.get(3).toString());
                String codDoc = fila.get(4).toString().split("-")[0];

                double num = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(6).toString());
                long numero = (long)num;
                String netoAfecto = getQuitaNegativo(numero + "");

                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(7).toString());
                long numero2 = (long)num2;
                String iva = getQuitaNegativo(numero2 + "");
                if(iva.equals("0"))
                    iva = "0";
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(8).toString());
                long numero1 = (long)num1;
                String netoExcento = getQuitaNegativo(numero1 + "");

                double num4 = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(10).toString());
                long numero4 = (long)num4;
                String total = getQuitaNegativo(numero4 + "");
                String tasaImp = (iva.trim().equals("")) ? "0" : "19";
                String filaString = "V;" + codDoc + ";" + nDoc + ";" + fechaDoc + ";0;" + rutDoc + ";" + razonSoc + ";" + netoAfecto 
                    + ";" + netoExcento + ";0;" + iva + ";" + tasaImp + ";" + total;

                csvOutput.write(filaString);
                csvOutput.endRecord();
            }
            if(salida == 1) break;
        }

        csvOutput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
    }
    return "Se ha creado el archivo correctamente: " + outputFile;
}

private String escribeLibroCompra(List cellDataList, String dirSalida, int año, String mes, String tipoLibro) throws IOException {
    String outputFile = dirSalida + "/" + tipoLibro +  "_" + mes +  año  + "_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".csv";
    String encCompra =  "TipoLibro;TipoDoc;NroDoc;FechaDoc;Anulado;RutDoc;RazonSoc;MontoNeto;MontoExe;MontoIVA;TasaImp;MontoImpAdd28"
            + ";MntIVANoRec;CodIVANoRec;MntTotal";
    try {
        ArrayList filas = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList celdas = new ArrayList();

        //pregunta si existe el archivo scv de compra o venta
        boolean alreadyExists = new File(outputFile).exists();
        if(alreadyExists) {
            File archivoLibro = new File(outputFile);
            archivoLibro.delete();
        }

        CsvWriter csvOutput = new CsvWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile, true), '\t');
        csvOutput.write(encCompra);
        csvOutput.endRecord();
        for (int i = 2; i < cellDataList.size(); i++) {
            List cellTempList = (List) cellDataList.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < cellTempList.size(); j++) {
                XSSFCell hssfCell = (XSSFCell) cellTempList.get(j);
                celdas.add(hssfCell.toString());
            }
            filas.add(celdas);
            celdas = new ArrayList();
        }

        int salida = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < filas.size() ; x++) {
            ArrayList fila = (ArrayList) filas.get(x);
            if(fila.get(0).toString().toLowerCase().contains("cuadro")) {
                salida = 1;
                break;
            }
            if(!fila.get(0).toString().toLowerCase().contains("total")) {
                Date fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", new Locale("es", "CL")).parse(fila.get(0).toString());
                String fechaDoc = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(fecha);
                String razonSoc = cortaTexto(fila.get(1).toString(),45);
                String rutDoc = fila.get(2).toString();
                String nDoc = getQuitaMontoCeros(fila.get(3).toString());
                String codDoc = fila.get(4).toString().split("-")[0];

                double num = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(6).toString());
                long numero = (long)num;
                String netoAfecto = getQuitaNegativo(numero + "");
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(7).toString());
                long numero1 = (long)num1;
                String netoExcento = getQuitaNegativo(numero1 + "");

                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(8).toString());
                long numero2 = (long)num2;
                String iva = getQuitaNegativo(numero2 + "");
                if(iva.equals("0"))
                    iva = "0";

                double num3 = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(9).toString());
                long numero3 = (long)num3;
                String impEspecifico = getQuitaNegativo(numero3 + "");
                if(impEspecifico.equals("0"))
                    impEspecifico = "";

                double num4 = Double.parseDouble(fila.get(10).toString());
                long numero4 = (long)num4;
                String total = getQuitaNegativo(numero4 + "");

                String tasaImp = (iva.trim().equals("")) ? "0" : "19";
                String filaString =  "C;" + codDoc + ";" + nDoc + ";" + fechaDoc + ";;" + rutDoc + ";" + razonSoc + ";" + netoAfecto 
                    + ";" + netoExcento + ";" + iva + ";" + tasaImp + ";" + impEspecifico + ";;;" + total;

                csvOutput.write(filaString);
                csvOutput.endRecord();
            }
            if(salida == 1) break;
        }

        csvOutput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
    }
    return "Se ha creado el archivo correctamente: " + outputFile;
}

public String getQuitaMontoCeros(String sMonto){
    for(int x = 0 ; x < sMonto.length() ; x++){
        String a = sMonto.substring(x, x + 1);
        if(!a.equals("0")){
            return sMonto.substring(x);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

public String getQuitaNegativo(String sMonto){
    if(sMonto.contains("-")){
        return sMonto.substring(1);
    }
    return sMonto;
}

public String cortaTexto(String sTexto, int nLargoMax) {
    sTexto = sTexto.replace("¥", "Ñ");
    if (sTexto != null && sTexto.length() > nLargoMax) {
        sTexto = sTexto.substring(0, nLargoMax);
    }
    return sTexto;
}
```

}

Y tengo el siguiente error:

```
    C:\Users\cons00\Desktop\Soportes\Pucobre\respaldo\librocomprasabril2016.xlsx
C:\Users\cons00\Desktop
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap
    at bcn.pucobre.controlador.ProcesaArchivo.procesaLibro(ProcesaArchivo.java:48)
    at bcn.pucobre.vista.PanelConector.jButton4ActionPerformed(PanelConector.java:308)
    at bcn.pucobre.vista.PanelConector.access$400(PanelConector.java:15)
    at bcn.pucobre.vista.PanelConector$5.actionPerformed(PanelConector.java:199)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 40 more
```

las dos primeras lineas son un print de las variables File y Directorio de salida

Comment: ¿Podrías poner todo el stackTrace como texto en lugar de imagen?

Comment: ¿Has importado el jar correspondiente?

Answer (score 1):

Este error aparece en tu proyecto, una de las clases que utilizas (o dependes) en este caso `ListValuedMap` esta presente dentro de tu proyecto en tiempo de compilación pero no en tiempo de ejecución. Tal como te comentan, debes asegurarte de que importaste todos los jar de las clases de las que depende tu librería.

Puedes descargar esta librería desde [aqui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0)

En la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) de esta pregunta en Stack over flow en ingles, te explican ademas, ciertas excepciones que debes controlar para identificar bien el error, tambien te explican a que se debe el error. Asi cuando recibas la excepcion puedes verificar mejor el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias efectivamente ese era el error!

Comment: un saludo @FelipeInostroza!